# Check if the user has role in sessions (PHP)

Tags: php

For a school project I'm looking if I can get the user role from the session (I have a role ID, but need to show data ONLY if the user has the correct role ID).

This is my code, but somehow only the first 'if' statement works...

```
<!-- check what role the user has and show data specifically for that user -->
    <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['userRole']) == 1){
            echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userRole"] . "</h3> "; 
            echo "<p>Jouw rol is Algemene Medewerker </p>";
        } 
        else if(isset($_SESSION['userRole'] )  == 2){
            echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userName"] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>Jouw rol is Medewerker Inname</h3><p>";
        } 
        else if(isset($_SESSION['userRole']) == 3){
            echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userName"] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>Jouw rol is Medewerker Verwerking</p>";
        } 
        else if(isset($_SESSION['userRole'])  == 4){
            echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userName"] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>Jouw rol is Medewerker Uitgifte</p>";
        } 
        else if(isset($_SESSION['userRole']) == 5){
            echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userName"] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>Jouw rol is Applicatie Beheerder</p>";
        } 
        else if(isset($_SESSION['userRole']) == 6){
            echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userName"] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>Jouw rol is Administrator</p>";
        }
        else {
           echo "<p>you are logged out</p>";
        } 
        
    ?>
```

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['userRole'])` will be a `Boolean` so you cannot test for equality in that expression. You ought to use `if( isset( $_SESSION['userRole'] ) && (int)$_SESSION['userRole']==1 )` etc

Comment: Only check once if the userRole is set. Then use a switch case to handle the possiblities. The reason the first one works is because true is a constant for 1.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? `isset` will never return any integer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment made previously regarding `isset` - that function returns a `boolean` so you can test for truthy values but not equate to a particular value as you do above. `isset` will take either a single or multiple values - `"If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered"`

There seems to be some duplication in the above code( not to mention the incorrect use of `isset` - I'd be tempted to rewrite that a little like this:

```
<?php 

    if( isset( $_SESSION['userRole'], $_SESSION["userName"] ) ){
        switch( (int)$_SESSION['userRole'] ){
            case 1:$message='Jouw rol is Algemene Medewerker'; break;
            case 2:$message='Jouw rol is Medewerker Inname'; break;
            case 3:$message='Jouw rol is Medewerker Verwerking';break;
            case 4:$message='Jouw rol is Medewerker Uitgifte';break;
            case 5:$message='Jouw rol is Applicatie Beheerder';break;
            case 6:$message='Jouw rol is Administrator';break;
        }
        
        
        printf('
            <h3 class="dashboard-welcome">Welkom %s</h3>
            <p>%s<p>',
            $_SESSION["userName"],
            $message
        );
    }else{
        echo "<p>you are logged out</p>";
    }
?>
```

An alternative using an array to `lookup` the role

```
    if( isset( $_SESSION['userRole'], $_SESSION['userName'] ) ){
    
        $i=(int)$_SESSION['userRole'];
        
        $roles=array(
            1=>'Algemene Medewerker',
            2=>'Medewerker Inname',
            3=>'Medewerker Verwerking',
            4=>'Medewerker Uitgifte',
            5=>'Applicatie Beheerder',
            6=>'Administrator'
        );
        
        printf('
            <h3 class="dashboard-welcome">Welkom %s</h3>
            <p>Jouw rol is %s<p>',
            $_SESSION["userName"],
            $roles[$i]
        );
    }else{
        echo "<p>you are logged out</p>";
    }
```

I assumed that `>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userRole"] . "` was a mistake and also there was a stray `</h3>` tag in 2nd piece of logic ( after: `isset($_SESSION['userRole'] )  == 2` )

Comment: Good solution but code formatting from hell

Comment: how kind to say so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions :

1. create a table of users roles:

```php
$users_roles = array(
1 => "Algemene Medewerker",
2 => "Medewerker Inname",
3 => "Medewerker Verwerking",
4 => "Medewerker Uitgifte",
5 => "Applicatie Beheerder",
6 => "Administrator"
);
```

and then use it directly

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['userRole'])) {
    echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userName"] . "</h3>";
    echo "<p>Jouw rol " .  $users_roles[$_SESSION['userRole']] . "</p>";
}
?>
```

2. modify `$_SESSION['userRole']` to set real value ("Algemene Medewerker", "Medewerker Inname"...) and not integer

Answer (score 0):

You can you and operator like this;

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userRole']) and $_SESSION['userRole']== 1){
        echo "<h3 class='dashboard-welcome'>Welkom " . $_SESSION["userRole"] . "</h3> "; 
        echo "<p>Jouw rol is Algemene Medewerker </p>";
    }
...
```

isset function avoids the warning if the session does not exist